# how do i remove a key from a dictionary when the key is a space bar

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def search4vowels(word):
    """fucntion searchs for vowels from a given string input("") & counts them """
    vowels = set("aeiou")
    vowels = str(vowels)
    found = {}
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            found.setdefault(letter, 0)
            found[letter]+=1
    for k,v in sorted(found.items()):
        print (k,"has",v,"vowels in the sentence",word)
```

how do i remove/delete or pop the space bar key & value in the found dictionary if i was to write a given sentence as the word function argument

Comment: `mydict.pop(' ', None)`

Comment: Why do you want to remove spaces? They won't be added to `found` in the first place.

Comment: There shouldn't be any space keys in the dictionary, since you only add vowels.

Comment: Why do you change `vowels` from a set to a string? A set is more appropriate for testing membership. And if you want it to be a string, just do `vowels = "aeiou"` without first creating the set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your interpreter:

```
str(set("aeiou"))
```

The result is:

> "{'a', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'e'}"

As the string representation of that data structure contains spaces, the code you posted therefore believes that a space is a vowel. Several punctuation characters are also vowels. Obviously this isn't what you want.

As suggested in comments, it would be better to simply use

```
vowels = "aeiou"
if letter in vowels:
    stuff
```

Because "in" is expected to work on a set, vowels = set("aeiou") would have worked, and is better practice. Just don't take the string representation. In the case of a five character string, performance isn't a concern, but set provides better lookup for existence in an arbitrarily large data set.

Oh yes, just to answer the question literally, the first comment (Paul H) is correct on how you can remove a key from the dict, after having added it by mistake.

```
found.pop(' ', None)
```

Comment: That is amazing ,thankyou all. i have been practicing in the interpreter, i now understand thankyou :)